# For which species is Risa climate-controlled?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

En route to Risa just prior to being abducted by the Romulans, Geordi asks the shuttle computer what the weather is like down on the planet. The computer responds by telling him that Risa is climate-controlled for optimum tourist comfort.

Which tourists are in view? Humans only? Any humanoids? I find it hard to believe that all humanoids would be optimally comfortable in the same climate. Ferengis, Klingons, Bajorans, Andorians, Vorgons, and many others surely don't all agree precisely on what climate is best, comfort-wise, for "vacation" or rest.

Perhaps there are different areas on Risa, each with a different climate. Or maybe individuals can choose their own climate, as like in a holodeck.

Comment: It would certainly be odd if all of Risa had exactly the same climate, from the equator to the poles.  They *could* do that with climate control, I suppose, but it seems likely to cause a great deal of trouble.  Most likely each area is maintained at a climate similar to its original climate type, whatever that might be, but regulated to avoid storms and other excessive variations.  Tourists can pick and choose.

Comment: @HarryJohnston It *would* be odd if an entire planet had the same climate, *except* that it's the sort of thing you see so often in (soft) SF. (eg [Vulcan](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Vulcan_(planet)), Hoth, Tattooine, ...)

Comment: @Adeptus: any canon evidence that Vulcan doesn't have polar ice caps?  (I suppose we see it from space occasionally, but I don't recall offhand.)  Same goes for Tatooine.  Ice planets like Hoth and Andor (?) are sound IMO.  Some parts will be colder than others, but it's all going to look the same as far as we're concerned.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - [Vulcan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbZky.png) doesn't have any icecaps.

Comment: @Valorum:   You can see them on the MA page that Adeptus linked.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Interesting, and worthy of its own question. Why does Vulcan appear to have a Northern Polar capping of ice in the remastered TOS but nowhere else

Comment: @Valorum:   Go for it.

Comment: @Valorum, it occurred to me yesterday evening that desert planets are really no different in this respect to ice planets, they could well have a *wide* range of climates, varying from mild desert to puddles-of-boiling-lead desert.  I imagine you wouldn't see the difference from space. (Not that I think the writers put that much thought into it, I'm just saying the idea can be steelmanned.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the script for [TNG: Captain's Holiday](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/167.txt), the temperate is held at 83°F (28.3°C), perfect for humans and, presumably, Risian humanoids.

That temperature would be too low for comfort for a Vulcan and far too high for comfort for an Andorian.

> Another perfect day at the Pleasure Haven. The temperature is the
>   equivalent of a balmy eighty-three degrees Fahrenheit; a warm breeze
>   prevents the heat from becoming oppressive, and the water (you'll have
>   to take my word for it because we never get to see the ocean) is as
>   clear and calm as a lake.

The implication seems to be that their weather control is [planet-wide](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SingleBiomePlanet) (hence the lack of polar ice or more active pursuits like skiing).

Comment: I don't see the implication. The quote only describes the weather at Pleasure Haven, a specific holiday ressort.

Comment: This human thinks 28.3 °C is too hot, far from perfect.

Comment: @chirlu - In which case you can nip over to the Risian Sexatorium until it cools off a little in the afternoon.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like a lot of humanoids in Trek have roughly similar biological preferences. All of the species you listed - plus a bunch more - co-exist in the climate-controlled environment of a starship without significant difficulty.

If *I* were designing a climate-controlled tourist planet, I would set up resorts on every available biome and adjust from there: tropical islands for the Humans, deserts for the Vulcans, polar outposts for the Andorians, and whatever would make the Klingons most *un*comfortable, since they seem to be into that. ;)

Comment: Klingons like *pain*, not discomfort. They'll enjoy a good round with the pain sticks, but hate the cold.

Comment: Torture me like one of your french girls for breakfast. HARDER! But please no climate below freezing point. :/

Comment: At least two of the species mentioned complain about the temperature on a Federation Starship. I guess when you're a minority, you're just expected to suck it up.